# Start Activity Indicator View before launching NSTask Objective-c ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityindicatorview, nstask

In my app, I've several buttons that, when pressed, launch an NSTask. It works well but I would like to inform the user when this task begin and when it finish by showing an Activity Indicator View (the little gray wheel).

Does anybody can give me an hints to add this functionnality ? Thanks in advance !

PS: I'm aware that launching external code is not allowed by Apple, I don't want to publish this app to the AppStore but to Cydia instead.

Comment: What research did you do? A quick google of "uiactivityindicatorview example" yields all sorts of promising links.

Comment: I have to admit that I 've didn't searched that way, "activity indicator before nstask", this kind of things... You can blame me ^^ thanks for your tips, I've found my answer :)